# Отрисовка таблицы с данными из динамического массива PHP

Tags: php, динамические-массивы, таблицы

Помогите пожалуйста с отрисовкой таблицы HTML, с данными из динамического массива. С внесением в БД объяснили, понял, а вот с отрисовкой таблицы не могу догнать. Сам массив такого рода:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [w1] => 1 [w2] => 3 [res] => 3 ) 
[1] => Array ( [w1] => 1 [w2] => 2 [res] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [w1] => 1 [w2] => 4 [res] => 4 ) 
[3] => Array ( [w1] => 3 [w2] => 2 [res] => 6 ) 
[4] => Array ( [w1] => 3 [w2] => 4 [res] => 12 ) 
[5] => Array ( [w1] => 2 [w2] => 4 [res] => 8 ) 
)
```

Сама таблица должна составляться такого рода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень признателен и благодарен!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$results = array ( 
    array ("w1" => 1, "w2" => 3, "res" => 3 ),
    array ("w1" => 1, "w2" => 2, "res" => 2 ),
    array ("w1" => 1, "w2" => 4, "res" => 4 ),
    array ("w1" => 3, "w2" => 2, "res" => 6 ),
    array ("w1" => 3, "w2" => 4, "res" => 12 ),
    array ("w1" => 2, "w2" => 4, "res" => 8 )
);

$keys = array();
//получаем все возможные ключи массивов для шапки
foreach ($results as $data){
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($data));
}
//удаляем повторы
$keys = array_unique($keys);
echo "<table style=\"border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center;\">
        <thead style=\"background-color: #000; color: #fff;\">
            <th style=\"padding: 2px 10px;\">#</th>";
            foreach ($keys as $key){
                //выводим шапку из ключей
                echo "<th style=\"padding: 2px 10px;\">".$key."</th>";
            }
        echo "</thead>
        <tbody>";
            for($counter=0; $counter<count($results); $counter++){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td  style=\"border: 1px solid #000; font-weight: bold;\">".($counter + 1)."</td>";
                    foreach ($keys as $key){
                        echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid #000;\">";
                        //если в массиве есть элемент с ключём, выводим его
                        if(isset($results[$counter][$key])){
                            echo $results[$counter][$key]."</td>";
                        }
                        echo "</td>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "<tbody>
</table>";
```

Comment: нечитабельный вариант, сложно понять что здесь происходит. 
count($results) нельзя кидать в условие цикла

Comment: А почему не читабельный и не понятный, можете по конкретней, если не сложно? На счёт count($results) - да, всё верно говорите, моё упущение

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно, шапка составляется не из ключей, а из значений, последующие строки заполняются значением, соответствующим значению шапки (в том же столбце) и последний столбец - результат выведенных значений строки.